# Docking Station Won't Recognize Second Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, docking-station

I have an Acodot docking station that has one HDMI connection and one DVI connection. My first external monitor (connected HDMI to HDMI) reads fine. My second external monitor (connected HDMI to an adapter HDMI to DVI) does not read at all. I changed the laptop setting so nothing is affected when the laptop is closed. I feel like there's a setting I'm missing but I don't know. Any help is appreciated.